# Given a TCP server, how to get the connection domain address

Tags: go, tcp

I have a simple TCP server and, when a client connects, I want to get the domain address used to connect:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net"
    "os"
)

const (
    CONN_HOST = "localhost"
    CONN_PORT = "3333"
    CONN_TYPE = "tcp"
)

func main() {
    // Listen for incoming connections.
    l, err := net.Listen(CONN_TYPE, CONN_HOST+":"+CONN_PORT)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error listening:", err.Error())
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    // Close the listener when the application closes.
    defer l.Close()
    fmt.Println("Listening on " + CONN_HOST + ":" + CONN_PORT)
    for {
        // Listen for an incoming connection.
        conn, err := l.Accept()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Error accepting: ", err.Error())
            os.Exit(1)
        }
        // Handle connections in a new goroutine.
        go handleRequest(conn)
    }
}

// Handles incoming requests.
func handleRequest(conn net.Conn) {
    // Make a buffer to hold incoming data.
    buf := make([]byte, 1024)
    // Read the incoming connection into the buffer.
    _, err := conn.Read(buf)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error reading:", err.Error())
    }
    // Send a response back to person contacting us.
    conn.Write([]byte("Message received."))
    // Close the connection when you're done with it.
    conn.Close()
}
```

I tried debugging the `conn net.Conn` param but I can't find any reference to the domain address. Tried with http://test.127.0.0.1.xip.io:3333/ and I'm interested in getting `test.127.0.0.1.xip.io` somehow. Any ideas?

Comment: If I recall correctly, you cannot access the "domain" name on raw TCP connections, whether it be Go or any other language. You might want to consider spinning up an HTTP server if you need the hostname that was used to hit your service.

Comment: There is no general way to do this. Any given IP address may be associated with any number of domains, anywhere from 0 to millions, or more, and by different means. The first step is to define what you mean by "the domain of the server".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are trying to do is not possible with plain TCP. TCP works on plain IP-Addresses without domains.

To explain what is going on:

When you are establishing a connection to, e.g. `example.com`, first of all a DNS Lookup for `example.com` is done. In this case, the DNS Lookup would result in `93.184.216.34`. You can read more about DNS [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System).

A TCP Connection with `93.184.216.34` is established after that, the original domain name is not sent with the request.

Because you sometimes need the original name the user was trying to connect to, some protocols send the domain name after connecting. HTTP for example does this via the [`Host` header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Host).

Maybe you can do something like that and require to send the original host first through your TCP Connection!

Comment: Ok. I knew that but I got puzzled by this service here running a DOT server: https://my.nextdns.io/a7ac6f/setup. They are able to spin up a DOT server (which is listening on TCP if I'm not mistaken/based on my research) and somehow manage to also receive the identifier (`a7ac6f`) when the client connects. This led me to believe there's something that I may be missing about this protocol and the connection address/fqdn is somehow passed to the server.