# How to forward requests from internet to k8s services

Tags: nginx, kubernetes

I tried to search, but I can't find nothing.

**What I have:**

- single node k8s cluster
- two game servers(project zomboid and valheim)
- some web app listening http requests

**My problem is**

I can't access my services. I don't know what to do to forward requests from internet directly to my services.

I tried to make nginx server on host machine and forward using reverse proxy. It is working good for http requests. I can forward each subdomain.domain.com to each of my services.

**My Questions**

1. What about tcp/udp requests?
2. How I can forward them?
3. Is it a good way having nginx on host machine?
4. Is it possible to route tcp/udp requests by domain name(e.g. mygameserver:700 redirects to gameserver1 ip and myanothergameserver:700 redirects to anothergameserver ip?

[kubectl get all](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WB2Gm.png)

Comment: [you found nothing, huh?](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=nginx+proxy+forward+tcp+udp&ia=web) (1) [yes](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/exposing-tcp-udp-services/) _(the 5th link in the results, BTW)_ (4) not without custom logic to reach into the TCP stream and sniff out routing details, which for sure nginx will not do

Comment: sorry, I just forgot to mention, that I found that article about nginx streams, but I wasn't 100% sure, that it is what I need.

Anyway, to refer to services cluster IP, I have to make nginx-ingress-controller where I can specify cluster IP, am I right? I will have 1 nginx on host machine, and another one in cluster ingress service

Also, could you direct me with domain name redirecting for tcp/udp requests, I tried to search(really ;) ) but found only for http requests. Could you share some key words for searching?

Thank you very much!

Comment: I found this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61889538/given-a-tcp-server-how-to-get-the-connection-domain-address

Comment: @Azamat so another stackoverflow thread you mention solved your issue or you still have some questions?

Comment: @Azamat any updates? mdaniel already provided you a lot of proper docs. Do you still have any questions? In your output one svc is `nodeport` and nother `clusterip`, could you share your configs?

Comment: HI @PjoterS, Thank you for your reply and thanks to mdaniel. Yeah, I totally figured out how nodeport works on k8s. The last my question is 4th. It was answered too, but could you help with resources, I can't build properly google query again =) 

I want to have ability to route udp requests by domain. Google gives info like "DNS based on UDP/TCP requests"

Comment: What do you mean by `google query`?  Do you mean [kubectl port forward](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/port-forward-access-application-cluster/) ?

Comment: I mean googling =)